# arquillian testng test do not start jboss managed

Tags: jboss7.x, testng, jboss-arquillian

My scenario is to launch arquillian tests on a jboss managed.
Actually my ear are already deployed on Jboss, so I'm not putting any archive there with ShrinkWrap.
My tests run on testng.
To start Jboss I provided a custom maven profile as the arquillian docs suggest:

```
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                 </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>           
    </profile>
```

Actually my Jboss never starts, and I'm not able to figure out what's going on. 
Maven debug do not provide any info on the facts he's tried to start the boss.

What on Arquillian triggers the starting of the server ?
There's some kind of hook I can rely upon?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Interesting question. So how i understood this working is that you select your container connector - which you already did jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed. When you start your JUnit test (having  @RunWith(Arquillian.class) Arquillian will load the available connector which in your case should be the managed one. What i don't see how your scenario fails? The tests starts but than hits a connection refused?

Comment: In my previous comment i meant TestNG not JUnit sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my mistake:

I did not include this dependency in the pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Without it no exception it thrown but the server does not start. 
A bit tricky actually...

Answer (score 0):

For Arquillian triggers the starting of the server TestNG-tests class must extends Arquillian also.

```
    @Test(groups = "test")
    public class TestServiceNGTest extends Arquillian {
      @Deployment
      public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addClass(TestService.class);

          System.out.println(war.toString(true));
      return war;
      }
    // ... tests sources 
    }
```